# Phantomjs switching to incorrect iframe

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, phantomjs

I'm using phantomjs v. 2.0.1 (have 1.9.2 too) + python + selenium.
Have faced with a strange behaviour when switched to iframe element. I had found iframe element I needed and tried to switch to it. But actually switched to another iframe in that html. This trick reproduces for 100% and I have no idea why this happens.
Tried Firefox web driver and it works as needed without the surprise (same python code)
Any ideas?

```
boxframe = WebDriverWait(driver, 8).until(lambda driver :driver.find_element_by_xpath('//iframe[starts-with(@title, "...") and not(@disabled)]'))
driver.switch_to.frame(boxframe)
```

Comment: Your code and the page please?

Comment: I cant provide the page. This is just a page of google service

Comment: There must be several iframes then. Try to get all the iframes inside an array and then identify your desired iframe using index of the array.

Comment: Thanks. There are at least 2 iframes. I'm getting iframes list and detecting that one I need. Then switching to it, but phantom switches to another one. e.g. phantom switches to iframe with index J when i'm telling him switch to iframe with index K.
This is proved by inner html content I'm getting with js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have workarounded this issue using BeautifulSoup package. After I have downloaded page I am passing its source to the BS object and then search into this.

```
self.driver.get("mysite.com")
soup = BeautifulSoup(self.driver.page_source, 'html.parser')
rows = soup.findAll("div", { "class" : "dealRow" })
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a long time [issue](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/issues/10953) for phantomjs and gostdriver but seem like they haven't solved the problem yet. Instead you **may** use `execute_script` to have it done.

```
driver.execute_script("$x('//iframe[starts-with(@title, \'...\') and not(@disabled)]').contents().find('#elementid').click()")
```

Comment: Hey thanks. It is about GhostDriver, but seems to be relative to my issue too.
Could you please tell when this fix would be available in phantomjs? It is not fixed in latest release